# pass variables between forms through constructor or use public accessors?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that has a process that takes 3 screens (forms) to be completed. Should I pass the variables that i need from the first form to the second form (through constructor) and to the third form or should I create a public accessor on the first form that i will access from the second and the third form?

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: even better, don't make your forms dependent on other forms, have a data layer and use a service class to fetch the objects necessary for the form you're using. So your first form would "save" the data via the service (which might persist it to disk or database if appropriate, or just in memory) and then the next form retrieves the data it needs by calling a suitable method from the service. The only thing you might need to pass around is an ID to identify the correct object from your model to retrieve.

Comment: @ADyson you mean something like MVP?

Comment: Well I just had a general n-tier architecture in mind but if it helps to think in terms of MVP or MVC then yeah something like that is certainly better than creating direct inter-dependencies between your forms

Answer (score 0):

As has been mention in the comments, I'd recommend using a controller class which handles the data.

Essentially, an object that runs in the background, collects data and displays the forms as required, without the forms knowing anything of each other.

Essentially like so:

```
public class Controller {

    private bool _formHasExited = false;

    public static async void Main(string[] args) {

        var form1DataObject = default(MyType1);
        var form2DataObject = default(MyType2);
        var form3DataObject = default(MyType3);
        var form = default(Form);

        // Display first form, collect data
        using (form = new MyForm1()) {
            form.Exited += (s, e) => _formHasExited = true;
            await Task.Run(WaitForFormExit);
            form1DataObject = form.Data;
        }


        // Reset _formHasExited
        _formHasExited = false;
        using (form = new MyForm2(form1DataObject.RequiredData)) {
            form.Exited += (s, e) => _formHasExited = true;
            await Task.Run(WaitForFormExit);
            form2DataObject = form.Data;
        }

        // Reset _formHasExited
        _formHasExited = false;
        using (form = new MyForm3(form2DataObject.RequiredData)) {
            form.Exited += (s, e) => _formHasExited = true;
            await Task.Run(WaitForFormExit);
            form3DataObject = form.Data;
        }

        // All data required has been obtained
        // Do stuff with all data

    }

    void WaitForFormExit() {
        // Example wait
        while (!_formHasExited);
        // Return
    }

}
```

Just be sure to **not** block the main thread, otherwise your UIs will become unresponsive.